# Simple switch with optoisolator - CTR related

Tags: switches, opto-isolator

I would like to use a optoisolator to act as a simple low current switch, however I'm slightly confused about how to apply the CTR.

From this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80796/determining-the-input-current-of-an-optoisolator-based-on-output-current-and-ctr), I should be using the minimum value on the CTR chart of the [4N28 optoisolator](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf). So, for my application, I have 18mA going through the input, therefore the minimum CTR of 10% would yield a minimum output of 1.8mA. Does this mean that I can only have 1.8mA flowing through the output transistor? (the worst case scenario)

The device that I want to switch on requires a 0.52mA to flow through in order to turn on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should set the photodiode current to whatever condition the datasheet guarantees the CTR at. The Vishay version of the part (datasheet added to your question) specifies 10-20% ctr at 10mA, but if another vendor specifies 18mA as you've indicated, go with it.

The 10-20% CTR means that the phototransisistor will be biased to only allow 10-20% of the photodiode current, so yes, if the CTR is 10% and the diode current is 18mA, the transistor will only allow 1.8mA to flow worst-case. (You don't externally limit the current to 1.8mA - the phototransistor does.) Your 0.52mA load should work OK with the 18mA you've specified, just bear in mind that there will be a voltage drop across the collector-emitter of the phototransistor that you will need to factor into your design.